# How to record model execution time for each simulation in NetLogo?

Tags: netlogo

How to record model execution time for each simulation in NetLogo? I would like to get real time (e.g. 6 seconds/mins) after each simulation stops. Would it be possible to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `reset-timer` command when the run starts, and the `timer` reporter afterwards to get a result.

- http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#reset-timer
- http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#timer